# Transform character into date using sparklyr

Tags: r, date, sparklyr

Good afternoon,

After connecting and opening a csv-file in Spark (R) I've observed that the date columns were automatically transformed into character type. I have opted several methods to transform them back to Date, but still get NA values

The example of my code:

```
block1_value <- c(1000, 1500, 2000)
block2_value <- c("30.09.2019", "13.10.2019", "22.01.2020")
block3_value <- c("a", "b", "c")

df <- data.frame(block1_value, block2_value, block3_value)
```

Let's assume that my dates should be formatted like "%d.%m.%Y". How is it possible to transform then into Date format in sparklyr?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with the lubridate package?

Comment: Yes, and it does not work here, because I'm writing my code in Spark using sparklyr library. Standard solutions are not working unfortunately